# Cups and print server slowing down entire system

Tags: debian, cups, printer

I am a sysadmin, and my computers run Debian Jessie. (I know, I'm working on updating soon.) When I try to print to a network printer, sometimes it works flawlessly. Other times, however, the program I'm printing from will gray out and the print dialog will take forever to come up. All the programs on the  computer will hang. At times like these, running `lpstat -t` will hang as well. Furthermore, after a print job is completed, `lpstat -t` will show, indefinitely:

> Printer *printername* is idle. Enabled since *datetime*.
>   Waiting for printer to finish.

The printer usually accepts more jobs anyway.

Restarting CUPS will usually temporarily fix all of these problems, but I have been unable to identify the source. What can I do to fix this?

Update:

Looking in my log files, I see `cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown` over and over.

Comment: I can guess your network printer was not enough memory. How large file did you send to the network printer?You should check your network speed before you did network printing.

Comment: I have many network printers, and this problem only began recently.

Comment: When you said this problem only began recently. You should check your network. Maybe your network got a problem recently too. Maybe Someone sent a large file to network printer. Did you change anything on CUPS and print server recently?

Comment: Problem can in router also, `reboot` your router.

Comment: What does http://localhost:631 say? I think that web server is the most reliable interface to CUPS.